# eclipse content assist doesn't work on some android type?

Tags: eclipse

hi I am new to eclipse...

I was trying to do

```
private Button.OnClickListener btnTestOnClick = new Button.OnClickListener()
```

and after I type "private Button." there is no content assist...

Is this normal so I have to type OnClickListener or other cases everytime or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OnClickListener` is an inner interface of `android.widget.View` and shows in the content assist if you start with that class. Inherited inner classes or interfaces are not shown. I believe this is a known bug but can't find a reference yet.

Comment: Start with `... = new View. <ctrl-space>`.

Comment: you meant private View.OnClickListener btnTestOnClick = new View.OnClickListener() ? content assist appear after view but it doesn't appear after button...

Comment: Yes, but as it is valid to assign it to `Button.OnClickListener` you could even assign to that type. Typically you wouldn't store the listener in a variable and just do `myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ... });`.